# Why don't my LINQ query results match database SELECT query results?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I've confirmed that I'm using the same server/database however, SQL Server Profiler catches nothing on the trace when I run this query.

```
public ClaimsViewModel GetSingleItem(int id)
{
    using (var db = new dbMedcoreDataContext())
    {
        var claim = db.Claims.Single(x => x.Id == id);
        return BuildViewModel(claim);
    }
}
```

Here's what a sample record looks like:

[image]

So I mean OBVIOUSLY the Referring and Assisting DoctorId values are there, referencing Doctor #1. I see this in SSMS after a simple select:

```
SELECT * FROM Claims WHERE Id = 1
```

The `.Single()` query above, however, doesn't populate these values. They're left at 0.

There are no structured relationships in the database. In theory this was supposed to allow me to manipulate data more easily during testing.

## EDIT 3

Per comment, here's the CREATE TABLE code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Claims](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReferringDoctorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssistingDoctorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AuthorizationCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ServiceDateStart] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ServiceDateEnd] [datetime] NULL,
    [Height] [int] NULL,
    [Weight] [int] NULL,
    [InHospital] [bit] NULL,
    [fkPatientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Submitted] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Claims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Claims] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Claims_Deleted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Deleted]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Claims] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Claims_Submitted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Submitted]
GO
```

## EDIT 2

Per comment, here's the result of `?claim` in the Immediate Window. I changed some values between tests I think (so weight and height are probably different), but the Doctor Id values are still doing the same

```
?claim
{Ortund.Claim}
    AssistingDoctorId: 0
    AuthorizationCode: "1234"
    Deleted: false
    Height: 13
    Id: 1
    InHospital: false
    ReferringDoctorId: 0
    ServiceDateEnd: {2018-06-12 4:00:00 PM}
    ServiceDateStart: {2018-06-12 10:00:00 AM}
    Submitted: true
    Weight: 12
    _AssistingDoctorId: 0
    _AuthorizationCode: "1234"
    _Deleted: false
    _Height: 13
    _Id: 1
    _InHospital: false
    _ReferringDoctorId: 0
    _ServiceDateEnd: {2018-06-12 4:00:00 PM}
    _ServiceDateStart: {2018-06-12 10:00:00 AM}
    _Submitted: true
    _Weight: 12
    _fkPatientId: 1
    fkPatientId: 1
```

## EDIT

Per request, here's the `Claim` class (auto generated by the dbml)

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Claims")]
public partial class Claim : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _Id;

    private int _ReferringDoctorId;

    private int _AssistingDoctorId;

    private string _AuthorizationCode;

    private System.DateTime _ServiceDateStart;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _ServiceDateEnd;

    private System.Nullable<int> _Height;

    private System.Nullable<int> _Weight;

    private System.Nullable<bool> _InHospital;

    private int _fkPatientId;

    private bool _Deleted;

    private bool _Submitted;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnIdChanging(int value);
partial void OnIdChanged();
partial void OnReferringDoctorIdChanging(int value);
partial void OnReferringDoctorIdChanged();
partial void OnAssistingDoctorIdChanging(int value);
partial void OnAssistingDoctorIdChanged();
partial void OnAuthorizationCodeChanging(string value);
partial void OnAuthorizationCodeChanged();
partial void OnServiceDateStartChanging(System.DateTime value);
partial void OnServiceDateStartChanged();
partial void OnServiceDateEndChanging(System.Nullable<System.DateTime> value);
partial void OnServiceDateEndChanged();
partial void OnHeightChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnHeightChanged();
partial void OnWeightChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnWeightChanged();
partial void OnInHospitalChanging(System.Nullable<bool> value);
partial void OnInHospitalChanged();
partial void OnfkPatientIdChanging(int value);
partial void OnfkPatientIdChanged();
partial void OnDeletedChanging(bool value);
partial void OnDeletedChanged();
partial void OnSubmittedChanging(bool value);
partial void OnSubmittedChanged();
#endregion

    public Claim()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Id != value))
            {
                this.OnIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Id = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                this.OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ReferringDoctorId", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int ReferringDoctorId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ReferringDoctorId;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ReferringDoctorId != value))
            {
                this.OnReferringDoctorIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ReferringDoctorId = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ReferringDoctorId");
                this.OnReferringDoctorIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_AssistingDoctorId", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int AssistingDoctorId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._AssistingDoctorId;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._AssistingDoctorId != value))
            {
                this.OnAssistingDoctorIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._AssistingDoctorId = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("AssistingDoctorId");
                this.OnAssistingDoctorIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

     [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_AuthorizationCode", DbType="VarChar(50)")]
    public string AuthorizationCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this._AuthorizationCode;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._AuthorizationCode != value))
            {
                this.OnAuthorizationCodeChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._AuthorizationCode = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("AuthorizationCode");
                this.OnAuthorizationCodeChanged();
            }
        }
    }

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ServiceDateStart", DbType="DateTime NOT NULL")]
    public System.DateTime ServiceDateStart
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ServiceDateStart;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ServiceDateStart != value))
            {
                this.OnServiceDateStartChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ServiceDateStart = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ServiceDateStart");
                this.OnServiceDateStartChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ServiceDateEnd", DbType="DateTime")]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ServiceDateEnd
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ServiceDateEnd;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ServiceDateEnd != value))
            {
                this.OnServiceDateEndChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ServiceDateEnd = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ServiceDateEnd");
                this.OnServiceDateEndChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Height", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> Height
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Height;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Height != value))
            {
                this.OnHeightChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Height = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Height");
                this.OnHeightChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Weight", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> Weight
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Weight;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Weight != value))
            {
                this.OnWeightChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Weight = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Weight");
                this.OnWeightChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_InHospital", DbType="Bit")]
    public System.Nullable<bool> InHospital
    {
        get
        {
            return this._InHospital;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._InHospital != value))
            {
                this.OnInHospitalChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._InHospital = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("InHospital");
                this.OnInHospitalChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_fkPatientId", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int fkPatientId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._fkPatientId;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._fkPatientId != value))
            {
                this.OnfkPatientIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._fkPatientId = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("fkPatientId");
                this.OnfkPatientIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Deleted", DbType="Bit NOT NULL")]
    public bool Deleted
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Deleted;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Deleted != value))
            {
                this.OnDeletedChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Deleted = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Deleted");
                this.OnDeletedChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Submitted", DbType="Bit NOT NULL")]
    public bool Submitted
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Submitted;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Submitted != value))
            {
                this.OnSubmittedChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Submitted = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Submitted");
                this.OnSubmittedChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the source code for the `Claim` class.

Comment: What does dbMedcoreDataContext() do?  Based on the results you're getting, I would think that db.Claims has nothing in it.

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on the `return BuildViewModel(claim);` line and do `?claim` in the `Immediate Window` and share with us what is output as a result.

Comment: The attributes suggest it's expecting column names that begin with `_` - but it doesn't look like that's the case in the database.

Comment: @DaisyShipton those are the private backing fields for the public members which are named without the `_` appended to them

Comment: Whoops, apologies for that. Have you turned on logging to see what query is being generated?

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` for the SQL table.

Comment: Given the weight is different, are you 100% sure you are pointed at the right DB?

Comment: @mjwills I had truncated the table and provided new data as I normally do between tests. Mistake on my part in this case, but I have confirmed the Connection String used by LINQ To SQL is connecting to the correct database.

Comment: If you have a chance, switch to Entity Framework. LINQ-to-SQL is not longer maintained by Microsoft. Anyway, there's nothing obviously wrong in your code. Does the executed SQL query (from `Single()`) contain the ID fields in the SELECT?

Comment: Why is your Claim class a partial class?

Comment: Please share the SQL being generated - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-display-generated-sql .

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not mapping the property values to the Viewmodel in code which is not included in the question.